# How Do I retrieve mongodb data using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am following a course on Pluralsight but this chunk of code is not working.Error in console:

> mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
>                                ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:multivision');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error ...'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is because you have no documents in `message` collection in db `multivision`

Comment: There is collection in multivision; running terminal command, i got this: > use multivision
switched to db multivision
> db.messages.insert({message:'Hello Mongo'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
messages
system.indexes
> db.messages.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536bec38216b2b27c3348f5c"), "message" : "Hello Mongo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536e3d0b7ac54b7cb7fa4f87"), "message" : "Hello Mongo" }

Comment: Try to change you connection string to mongodb://localhost:27017/multivision